# Text Render a bit noisy, even at 200 samples

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I can't seem to figure out how to get a sharper text render that I am using for my animation.

Here are the Things that I have tried:
1: Increasing Samples to as high as 300
2: Turning font shadow off
3: Denoising

Whatever I do, the text still has that weird greyish black outline and in my animation on youtube, it plays blurry even at 720p HD.

I see other peoples text videos and theirs are always so sharp.

How can I improve my text render in the future?

I turned the world lighting all the way up and there is a weak lamp in the scene, albeit, far away from the text, but the world lighting should be enough i think.

[image]

[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g2XFX8F5T8ANV-9Yj6mxpud_atas2zxy/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your object is casting shadows on the plane. Not because of the font/text properties, but because of the way Cycles (path tracing) works. To avoid your text being seen as a shadow caster by Cycles, you can turn off the ray visibility of the text object:

- In the outliner, select the object `Text.thing`
- Go to "Object" context
- Open the "Visibility" section
- Open the "Ray Visibility" subsection
- Uncheck the "Diffuse" and "Glossy" property

Comment: omg, that worked. Now I'm sad cause I wished I had asked the question before I posted the video to youtube. Can't think of rendering all that again. Thank you so much, now I know how to make clearer text vids in the future.